# Typescript - cannot write file because it would override input file

Tags: typescript

For quite a while now I have been getting the error "Cannot write file '...' because it would overwrite input file." and I can not figure out why this error occurs. The error output is:
[image]

I know there are plenty of questions on StackOverflow about this issue, however none of them seemed to help.

This is my TSConfig:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "lib": ["ESNext"],
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "test/**/*.ts", "index.ts", ".eslintrc.js"],
    "exclude": ["coverage", "dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

As you can see, all files in `dist` are explicitly excluded. I have also tried adding `*.d.ts` to the `exclude` array, but that did not help either (which seems very strange to me).

I have also verified that this TSConfig file is indeed the one being used by the typescript compiler.

I am currently using typescript version 4.3.5, but the problem has been present for quite a while now (I can not remember for how long, but already before the switch to TS version 4).

Also, I have tried re-cloning the repository, moving the directory to another path (because TypeScript might struggle with the directory name `config`) and naturally also deleting the directory `dist`. In addition to that, I use the same TSConfig file in plenty of other projects but the problem only exists with this one.

Comment: Few things that could help debugging: 1. Can you try adding `"./dist/**/*"` on your tsConfig under `exclude`? 2. Have you tried changing your `outDir` to `./dist` rather than `dist`? 3. Can you double check you don't have any import from the dist directory?

Comment: Tried all three and the problem still persists.